# problems with rabbitmq cluster across 2 ubuntu 9.04 machines

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, rabbitmq

I keep getting unable_to_contact_cluster_nodes error

Has anyone seen this earlier and resolved it?

I am using rabbitmq-server 1.5.4 installed using ubuntu repositories. I have a hunch that this is something to do with ufw or some other network security measure, enabled by default in ubuntu, that is preventing connections.

#### The machine is pingable (I made an entry in /etc/hosts file)

pgatram@mzl005:~$ ping mz005
PING mz005 (192.168.0.22) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mz005 (192.168.0.22): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
64 bytes from mz005 (192.168.0.22): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
^C
--- mz005 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.023/0.024/0.026/0.005 ms

#### I cant get the cluster to work

pgatram@mzl005:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl cluster rabbit@mz005
Clustering node rabbit@mzl005 with [rabbit@mz005] ...
Error: {unable_to_contact_cluster_nodes,[rabbit@mz005]}

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly a firewall issue. You should be able to telnet to the other host on port 5672 (or whatever you specified in /etc/default/rabbitmq). If telnet can't connect then the port isn't open. As a sanity check, try telnet to localhost on port 5672.

If you can't telnet it'll be a firewall issue.

After that it's a case of opening the port and trying again.

Chris